# Flink fails on startup on Java 10. TaskManager: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C

Tags: scala, apache-flink

## Background

When launching Flink, I get an immediate failure in the logs, and subsequent attempts to run an application all fail. I have narrowed down the failure to being Java 10 specific, possibly with other preconditions.

## Repro

1. Download and unpack Flink 1.4.2 from [the official download page](http://flink.apache.org/downloads.html).
2. Switch to Java 10. My specific version information is in (1).
3. Start Flink with `./bin/start-local.sh`.
4. Observe the TaskManager logs. For example, `cat ./log/flink-ming-taskmanager-0-C02TJ6XBG8WN.log`. There will be a large amount of error output, as in (2).
5. Run any application. For example, `./bin/flink run ~/git/ming-data-frameworks-poc/flinkpoc/target/scala-2.11/flinkpoc_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --port 900`. My example application is in (3), but as far as I know, this happens with any application. It should fail with an error, as in (4)
6. Stop Flink with `./bin/stop-local.sh`.
7. Empty the Flink logs directory.
8. Switch to Java 8. My specific version information is in (5).
9. Repeat steps 3 - 7.
10. It should show a success message, as in (6). It should not fail with an error. The TaskManager logs should not contain the error output in step 4.

## Questions

Is this a known incompatibility? It is not documented as such. In particular, [the official quick start documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html) says:

> Flink runs on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. To be able to run Flink,
>   the only requirement is to have a working Java 7.x (or higher)
>   installation.

How can this issue be fixed or worked around on Java 10?

Is this a bug in Flink? Should it be reported upstream to the project?

Thank you in advance for any advice or help you may have.

## Supplemental information

(1)

```
$ uname -a
Darwin C02TJ6XBG8WN 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Tue Jan 30 11:27:06 PST 2018; root:xnu-3789.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

(2)

```
2018-05-11 17:19:05,353 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [[B cannot be cast to [C] 
2018-05-11 17:19:10,428 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
2018-05-11 17:19:23,111 ERROR akka.remote.Remoting                                          - [B cannot be cast to [C
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C
    at akka.remote.artery.FastHash$.ofString(LruBoundedCache.scala:18)
    at akka.remote.serialization.ActorRefResolveCache.hash(ActorRefResolveCache.scala:61)
    at akka.remote.serialization.ActorRefResolveCache.hash(ActorRefResolveCache.scala:55)
    at akka.remote.artery.LruBoundedCache.getOrCompute(LruBoundedCache.scala:110)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.resolveActorRef(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:403)
    at akka.actor.SerializedActorRef.readResolve(ActorRef.scala:433)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1250)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1585)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2346)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2078)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1585)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:328)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:328)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.akka$serialization$Serialization$$deserializeByteArray(Serialization.scala:156)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$2.apply(Serialization.scala:142)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:136)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:30)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:82)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:1047)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:1046)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader.akka$remote$EndpointReader$$deliverAndAck(Endpoint.scala:1046)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:980)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:446)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

(3)

### `build.sbt`

```
name := "flinkpoc"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val flinkVersion = "1.4.2"

libraryDependencies := Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion % "provided"
)
```

### `SimpleJob.scala`

```
package flinkpoc

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

object SimpleJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val inStream = env.fromCollection(Range(0, 100).toList)
    val outStream = inStream.map(_ * 100)
    outStream.print

    env.execute("flinkpoc.SimpleJob")
  }

}
```

(4)

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:492)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.scala:638)
    at flinkpoc.SimpleJob$.main(SimpleJob.scala:14)
    at flinkpoc.SimpleJob.main(SimpleJob.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:525)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:417)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:802)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1101)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1098)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1098)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:387)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:481)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorConnectionTimeoutException: Lost connection to the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor.handleMessage(JobClientActor.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.handleLeaderSessionID(FlinkUntypedActor.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.onReceive(FlinkUntypedActor.java:71)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:165)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

(5)

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

(6)

```
Program execution finished
Job with JobID b41e26f012480d2842cbb8bde0098180 has finished.
Job Runtime: 379 ms
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. Flink 1.4 dropped support for Java 7, and Java versions 9 and 10 aren't supported yet. You'll need to use Java 8.

Update:

[Flink-8033](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8033) is the Jira issue tracking Java 9 support.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It was surprising (even counter intuitive) to run into. Glad to hear it's a known issue.

Comment: FYI, I've opened a pull request to clarify/fix this: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6010

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully, that will help anyone who runs into this in the future.